# QTreeWidget: Windows Explorer-like editing

Tags: c++, python, qt4, pyqt4

I want to create a `QTreeWidget` where the items are both editable and launchable. I want it to behave like Windows Explorer:

Single click -> selection

Single click on a previously selected item -> open LineEdit to edit the name

Double click -> perform the 'launch'

So I created slots for `itemClicked()` and `itemDoubleClicked()`. The first one is the following:

```
def EditName(self, item, column):
    if self.lastclick == item:
        self.editItem(item)
    self.lastclick = item
```

The second one just 'launches' the file.

However, this kind of solution doesn't distinguish between a double click and two consecutive clicks, so the `QLineEdit` still appears after a double click. Is it possible to get rid of the editor forcibly? I tried a hack solution like hiding and showing the item but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set flags on your QTreeWidgetItem to include the ItemIsEditable option, and set the edit triggers on the QTreeWidget for SelectedClick

```
def populate( self, tree ):
    tree.setEditTriggers(tree.SelectedClicked)
    for i in range(10):
        item = QTreeWidgetItem(['Testing %02i' % i])
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | item.ItemIsEditable)
```